# Test if object is JKArray

Tags: objective-c, reflection, jsonkit

I want to see if the results of this call:

```
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
id contacts=[[results objectForKey:@"list"] objectForKey:@"Contact"];
```

Return an array or a dictionary.

I tried this:

```
    [contactdict isKindOfClass:[JKArray class]];
```

but JKArray is statically declared in the JSONKit.m file, so the xcode can't see it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what [`NSClassFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString) is for:

```
if ([contactDict isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"JKArray")])
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Excellent!
Thanks Richard : )

Comment: @PaulWand No problem, happy to help! Just don't forget to accept the answer when you can!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to simply add `@class JKArray;` to the top of the file where you're making this call. That just tells the compiler that there is a class named JKArray. The actual test happens at runtime of course.

Alternatively, you should be able do this:

```
[[contactDict className] isEqualToString:@"JKArray"];
```

or this:

```
[contactDict isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"JKArray")];
```

Comment: Correction: The actual test happens at link-time, not runtime.

Comment: I was referring to the `if ([contactDict isKindOfClass[JKArray class]])` test, which most certainly happens at runtime. You're correct in that the linker will throw an error if JKArray isn't defined in any of the compiled source files being linked. However, as long as it does exist, the program will link and work just fine. You will get one or more compiler warnings ("receiver 'JKArray' is forward class..."). The NSClassFromString or className comparison approaches are the better way to go.